# Как вытащить информацию?

Tags: javascript, json

```
[ { yesterday:
 [ '\nПостарайтесь не откладывать в долгий ящик составление распорядка действий на сегодняшний день. Чем раньше вы разберетесь с этим вопросом, тем меньше будет вероятность, что вас обвинят в бездействии в некоторый ответственный момент.\n' ],
today:
 [ '\nСегодня вам стоит повнимательнее отнестись к вопросу взаимопонимания. От того, насколько хорошо собеседник поймет вас, зависит довольно многое.\n' ],
tomorrow:
 [ '\nБезусловно, именно с хаоса все и начиналось, однако, устраивая хаос в собственной жизни, не стоит надеяться на то, что это в обязательном порядке станет началом чего-то нового и прекрасного. Чуть-чуть порядка вам не помешает.\n' ],
tomorrow02:
 [ '\nСегодня вы можете влюбиться, причем как в человека, которого вы видите впервые, так и хорошо знакомого. Если же сердце ваше занято, и вы не хотите ничего менять, то следует быть осторожным и всячески избегать лиц противоположного пола.\n' ] } ]
```

Как вот из этого Json'a вытащить today?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var array = [{
  yesterday: ['\nПостарайтесь не откладывать в долгий ящик составление распорядка действий на сегодняшний день. Чем раньше вы разберетесь с этим вопросом, тем меньше будет вероятность, что вас обвинят в бездействии в некоторый ответственный момент.\n'],
  today: ['\nСегодня вам стоит повнимательнее отнестись к вопросу взаимопонимания. От того, насколько хорошо собеседник поймет вас, зависит довольно многое.\n'],
  tomorrow: ['\nБезусловно, именно с хаоса все и начиналось, однако, устраивая хаос в собственной жизни, не стоит надеяться на то, что это в обязательном порядке станет началом чего-то нового и прекрасного. Чуть-чуть порядка вам не помешает.\n'],
  tomorrow02: ['\nСегодня вы можете влюбиться, причем как в человека, которого вы видите впервые, так и хорошо знакомого. Если же сердце ваше занято, и вы не хотите ничего менять, то следует быть осторожным и всячески избегать лиц противоположного пола.\n']
}];

console.log(array[0].today);
// console.log(array[0].today[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Я бы посоветовал вам подключить библиотеки axios, дальше отправляете запрос в файл:

`axios.get("file.json")`

Затем вам нужно обработать данные которые пришли с файла:

`axios.get("file.json").then(result => {
   let res = JSON.parse(result);
})`

JSON файл отправляет в результат JSON строку, поэтому мы парсим строку, чтобы можно было дальше с ней работать. Затем вы просто уже можете вывести строку в консоль, и увидете, что это обычный массив. Получить одну определённую строку с JSON не получится, для такого уже используют базы данных.